# Как по клику в RecyclerView вызвать другое активити?

Tags: android

Вот мой адаптер:

```
public class RobobetListGetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RobobetListGetAdapter.RobobetGetViewHolder> {

private List<RobobetGetModel> listGet;

public RobobetListGetAdapter(List<RobobetGetModel> list){
    this.listGet = list;
}

@Override
public RobobetGetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_robobet_get, parent, false);
    return new RobobetGetViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RobobetGetViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final RobobetGetModel searchModel = listGet.get(position);
    holder.roboter_com1.setText(searchModel.getHome());
    holder.robobet_com2.setText(searchModel.getAway());
    holder.robobet_com1_per.setText(searchModel.getPercent_home());
    holder.robobet_com1_per.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(searchModel.getPercent_home_color()));
    holder.robobet_com2_per.setText(searchModel.getPercent_away());
    holder.robobet_com2_per.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(searchModel.getPercent_away_color()));
    holder.robobet_com1_kf.setText(searchModel.getKf_home());
    holder.robobet_com2_kf.setText(searchModel.getKf_away());
    holder.robobet_rate_txt.setText(searchModel.getOdds());
    holder.robobet_count.setText(searchModel.getResult_home() + "\n" + searchModel.getResult_away());

    holder.cv_robobet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Click work"); //тут надо вызвать Intent

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listGet.size();
}

public class RobobetGetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   TextView roboter_com1, robobet_com2, robobet_com1_per, robobet_com2_per, robobet_com1_kf,
           robobet_com2_kf, robobet_rate_txt, robobet_count;
    CardView cv_robobet;

    public RobobetGetViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        roboter_com1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(robobet_com1);
        robobet_com2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.robobet_com2);
        robobet_com1_per = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.robobet_com1_per);
        robobet_com2_per = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.robobet_com2_per);
        robobet_com1_kf = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.robobet_com1_kf);
        robobet_com2_kf = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.robobet_com2_kf);
        robobet_rate_txt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.robobet_rate_txt);
        robobet_count = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.robobet_count);
        cv_robobet = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_robobet_list_get);
    }
}
```

}

а вот так я вызываю:

```
    private void initRecyclerViewListGet() {
    recyclerViewGet = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.robobet_list_get_cv);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerViewGet.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerViewGet.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RobobetListGetAdapter adapter = new RobobetListGetAdapter(initRvListGet());
    recyclerViewGet.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Я так понимаю что надо передать View, как это сделать?

Comment: «Я так понимаю что надо передать View» – куда? зачем? И чем Вас [`startActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) не устраивает?

Comment: А почему вы не можете вызвать интент там, где отметили и для чего и куда нужно в вашем понимании передавать View?

Comment: по клику на весь элемент списка, или на какой-то View внутри этого элемента?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вставьте этот код куда вы указали:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("message", "Your message text");
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало! А как быть если мне надо будут передать данные в новое активити?

Comment: @ТарасЖупник поправил ответ

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!